# PowerShell nesting issue

Tags: powershell, get-wmiobject

```
$remove = @('microsoft*','visual*')

Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product -ComputerName $CompName | Where-Object {
    $f = $_.name -notcontains $remove
    $remove | Where-Object { $f.($_) }
} | Format-Wide -Property Name -Column 1
```

I'm not sure how to nest this properly so that I can filter out the everything in `$remove` and display the rest of the programs. I'm not getting any errors it will wait for about 10 seconds then continue to the PS prompt.

Comment: To confirm, are you trying to remove anything that has a name starting with Microsoft or Visual ?

Comment: yes sir, but that array is going to grow. I need to filter out programs that I don't need to install. I was using Microsoft and visual just for testing.

Comment: What is `$f = $_.name -notcontains $remove` and `$f.($_)` supposed to accomplish? Please read up on how [PowerShell operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-3.0) work. You need something like `$n = $_.Name; -not ($remove | ? {$n -like $_})`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

notcontains looks for exact matches so won't help you here.
Simplest way is probably this, although your regex may get quite nasty if there's lots to exclude:

```
get-wmiobject -class Win32_Product -ComputerName $CompName | Where-Object {

$_.name -notmatch "^(Microsoft|Visual)."

} | Format-Wide -Property Name -Column 1
```

Comment: That did it, I tried this last night but I must have messed up something.